# Realm Image Storage Interoperability Android iOS (Swift / Java)

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, realm

Guten Burbon:

I'm working on a small project for a reference app running on android and iOS. The application will feature a database that stores entries with a key, title, description and an illustration (image). Since images in realm can only be stored in a data format (NSData on iOS) , I wanted to know if I can access and read this data on both iOS and android.

The idea is to provide the app's owner with the ability to make updates to the database (additonal entries) using just the realm browser without the need of having two independent database files.

Thank you very much

Comment: If you store it as base64, then both android and ios can read it, but store raw image in database is not preferred, should store it as raw jpg/png in your host and only store the URL to the database

Answer (score 0):

So long as the image data you store is in a format that both platforms can read (e.g., JPEG, PNG, GIF), and your application uses the exact same schema for the classes stored in your Realm, you should be able to do as you intend.